# Proof of limit by definition

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $h_n$ be defined on the interval $\mathbb{I}=[0,1]$ by the formula
>   $$h_n(x)=\begin{cases} nx, & 0\le x\le 1/n \\\\  \frac{n}{n-1}(1-x),
>  &1/n<x\le1.  \end{cases}$$
>
> Show, by definition, that $\lim(h_n)$ exists on $\mathbb{I}$.

I know just by looking at it if $x=0$ it converges, but I do not know how to prove this using the definition? What is giving me problems is the way it is written. I haven't dealt with a limit proof question written like this before.

Comment: szereg funkcyjny, I lilke it!

Comment: I think it converges to the function $1-x$ if $x\neq 0$. Choose $\epsilon >0$, then let $n$ be big enough so that $1/n<x\leq 1$, so you know you will use $\frac{n}{n-1}(1-x)$ and you can make this arbitrarly close to $1-x$ because $|(1-x)-\frac{n}{n-1}(1-x)|=\frac{1}{n-1}(1-x)$, and for a fixed $x$, the quantity $1-x$ is constant.

Comment: @cf16 Huh? You must be speaking polish.

Comment: @KanyeWest I never knew Kanye West was a math guy. Thanks for that hint!

Comment: @Q.matin Im a musical genius! The voice of a generation!

Comment: @KanyeWest I know you knew that it converges to $1-x$, but if I didnt know that how can i set it up accordingly?

Comment: @Q.matin how did you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $x>0$, if $n\gt\frac1x$, then $h_n(x)=\frac{n}{n-1}(1-x)$. Therefore, if $x\gt0$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}h_n(x)=1-x$.

For all $n$, $h_n(0)=0$. Thus,
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}h_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1-x&\text{if }x\gt0\\
0&\text{if }x=0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Thanks Rob, this is much more clear. Last question, Kayne in the comments related to $|(1-x)-\frac{n}{n-1}(1-x)|=\frac{1}{n-1}(1-x)$ by the defintion. How would I complete that?

Comment: Choose an $\epsilon\gt0$. Let $n\gt\max\left(\frac1x,1+\frac1\epsilon\right)$, then $\left|h_n(x)-(1-x)\right|=\frac1{n-1}(1-x)\le\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

for every x in [0,1] there exists n that $x> \frac{1}{n}$ so $\lim(h_n)(x)=\lim_n_{\infty}\frac{n}{n-1}(1-x)=1-x$ since x is constant

for x=1 and x=0 lim=0

Comment: except at $x=0$ where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}h_n(0)=0$

Comment: Thanks, I see why it converges to $1-x$ but how can I prove this using the defintion or will your answer be suffice?

Comment: @Q.matin yes, definition states that this series converges pointwisely to function $f_n$ if it converges in every point

Comment: @Q.matin and this function which is its convergence doesn't necessary have to be continuous (smooth)

Comment: @Q.matin you are very welcome